# exe file is not running in Release folder

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, release

My project IDE: Visual Studio 2019, Qt 5.15.0.

I'm trying to launch the application by the project_name.exe file of the release build, but nothing happens.

The project_name.exe file of Debug mode is running well.

The project is running well also in IDE in both Debug and Release modes.

I added Qt Bin directory to the PATH.

I tried windeployqt command but it didn't help.

I copied to Release folder all the dll files the application depends on, according to the build output and Dependencies tool, but then I couldn't run it neither from the exe file nor from the IDE (there are no any compilation errors or error messages when I'm trying to run it).

What is missing for running the exe file from Release folder?

Comment: Comment from user17537755: Sorry I cannot make comment because my reputation is too low. Do you mean that you can run the application in IDE with Working Directory = project directory, but cannot run with Working Directory = release directory? My guess is some files cannot be found because of the relative path, such as translation files. Have you tried to copy the .exe to the project dir and run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps finally solved my problem:

1. Copy the qml folder from the project directory into Release folder (it has to be
   near the exe file).
2. In Release folder launch Command prompt and write: windeployqt project_name.exe,
   this step must come after having qml files for getting the whole needed deployment
   files by windeployqt command.
3. Copy from your system the following dlls into Release folder: opengl32.dll,
   libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll.
4. For a VM with no Visual Studio installed there are some more dlls to copy.